# How long do I have to wait to dispose of evidence after nobody comes to collect it?

Tags: colorado

Suppose I find evidence of a murder on property I use for hunting purposes and I report it to the local sheriff. I don't know how my property ended up looking like that, but I do know that the evidence is unsightly at BEST, and I want it removed ASAP. Will I ever be able to legally remove it if the sheriff doesn't respond to my report, and how long must I wait to do so?

Comment: Are you saying you've reported a murder and the sheriff isn't responding, or is this post-incident crime scene clear up?

Comment: If someone has been arrested for the crime then you could contact their attorney; if the sherriff is ignoring potentially exculpatory evidence then that would seriously undermine the prosecution case.

Comment: @rock ape: I reported a murder but the sheriff didn’t show up.

Comment: Hypothetically of course